# What is the purpose of "-p" or "-t" in terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface

What is the purpose of -p and -t in the following terminal commands?

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
```

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

In general, I'm having trouble understanding the terminal commands with - followed by a letter. When I try to look it up the results often show commands such as cd or mkdir, maybe I'm looking up the wrong thing.

Comment: try running: man mkdir

Comment: Those are flags for different commands. Many console programs take flags. When you're unsure about the options for a command, check the documentation with `man name-of-command`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-p` flag is not something common to *all* terminal commands-- you can usually get help on terminal commands with either `man <the_command_in_question>` or something `<the_command_in_question> --help`.  In this case, you would find the following explanation for `mkdir`'s `-p` flag:

> Create intermediate directories as required.  If this option is not specified, the full path prefix of each operand must already exist.  On the other hand, with this option specified, no error will be reported if a directory given as an operand already exists.  Intermediate directories are created with permission bits of rwxrwxrwx (0777) as modified by the current umask, plus write and search permission for the owner.